# Keras binary_crossentropy vs categorical_crossentropy for multi class single label classification

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, classification

I've been using binary cross-entropy but recently found out I may be better off using cateogrical cross entropy.

For the problem I'm solving the following is true:

1. There are 10 possible classes.
2. A given input only maps to 1 label.

**I'm getting much higher accuracies with binary cross-entropy. Should I switch to categorical cross-entropy?**

At the moment I'm using standard accuracy (metrics=['accuracy']) and a sigmoid activation layer for the last layer. **Can I keep these the same?**

Comment: How do you solve 10-class problem with binary cross-entropy? Did you keep sigmoid activation when switched to categorical cross-entropy?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you have a multiclass problem and your classes are mutually exclusive. You should use `categorical_crossentropy` and change your output activation function to `softmax`.

`binary_crossentropy`, as the name suggests, must be used as loss function only for 2-class problems.